# How to use the law of total expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value

suppose we have to exponential random variable $X$ and $Y$ with $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$, if we consider $W=min(X,Y)$ then expected value of $W$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y}$.

Now i want to calulate the expected value of $W$ based on total law of expectation, this is what i did:

since expected value of $X$ and $Y$ are $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$ respectivly, so i write:
$$E[W]=E[X]P(X<Y)+E[Y]P(Y<X)=\frac{1}{\lambda_x}(\frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y})+\frac{1}{\lambda_y}(\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y})=\frac{2}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y}$$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ and $1_{\{X<Y\}}$ are not independent! You can write
$$
E[W]=E[X; X<Y]+E[Y; Y<X]
$$
(because the third possibility $X=Y$ has probability $0$). But to go further, you now need to integrate: for example,
$$
\eqalign{
E[X; X<Y]
&=\int_0^\infty \left[\int_0^y x f_X(x) dx\right] f_Y(y) dy\cr
&=\int_0^\infty\left[\int_x^\infty f_Y(y) dy\right] xf_X(x) dx.\cr
}
$$

Comment: thanks a bunch, very clear explanation.